# issue with implementation of keyListener for writting unicode (Sindhi) in java

Tags: java, swing, unicode, keylistener

I want to use unicode through the implementation of keyListener on `jTextField` in this way :

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            char var = evt.getKeyChar();
            if(var == 'a'){
                String values = urlTextField.getText() + Sindhi.ALIF;
                urlTextField.setText(values);
            }
        }
    });
```

but it writes `English` character`a` with `unicode` character `Sindhi.ALIF`. how to get only the `unicode` character written in `jTextField`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of your current problem, you shouldn't be using a KeyListener in a JTextField. Use a DocumentListener or DocumentFilter instead. Given your code, I'm guessing that a DocumentFilter is what you need, since you wish to change the text of the JTextField as it is being entered and before it is being displayed.

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class SwapAForAleph {
   // No idea of the correct unicode for this!!!
   public static final char SINDHI_ALIF = '\u0623'; 

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
      textField.setFont(textField.getFont().deriveFont(32f));
      PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) textField.getDocument();
      doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
         @Override
         public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text,
               AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            text = filterText(text);
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
         }

         @Override
         public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
               String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            text = filterText(text);
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
         }


         private String filterText(String text) {
            return text.replace('a', SINDHI_ALIF);
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(textField);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}
```

Or looked at in another way...

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class NonEnglishTextField {
   public static final char ALEPH = '\u05D0';

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
      textField.setFont(textField.getFont().deriveFont(32f));
      textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
      textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
      PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) textField.getDocument();
      doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
         @Override
         public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text,
               AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            text = filterText(text);
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
         }

         @Override
         public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
               String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            text = filterText(text);
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
         }


         private String filterText(String text) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (char c : text.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
               if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                  char newChar = (char) (c - 'a' + ALEPH);
                  sb.append(newChar);
               } else {
                  sb.append(c);
               }
            }
            return sb.toString();
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(textField);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}
```

Comment: but how to compare and replace other characters?

Comment: @ArshadAliSoomro: you write code to do that. Shoot, I've shown two different ways to do this in the code examples above! Check out the two different implementations of the `filterText(...)` method.

Comment: there is problem with this approach, it does not distinguish lower case letters and upper case letters e.g if I `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                  char newChar = (char) (c - 'A' + '\u0622'); 
                  sb.append(newChar);
               }`  , but it does not write my desired `\u0622`, and writes `ALIPH` instead. plz help...

Answer (score 2):

Use a DocumentFilter.

By the time the KeyListener recives the event, the character has already being added to the field.

Also KeyListener won't deal with the user pasting content into the field